# How do you combine nested IF statements with multiple outcomes in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

AU-contains numbers from 0-20
AV-needs to have high, moderate, low; based on the number in AU

=>5   HIGH
   3-4   MODERATE
   <3    LOW

Wrote this below, however I get #NAME? for the answer; so I know some part of it is wrong. Please help.

=IF(OR(AU>=5),"High",IF(OR(AU<=4.9>=3),"Moderate",IF(OR(AU<3),"Low")))

Comment: What is `AU` in this scenario? I think you're missing a row number after `AU`, which is causing your error. That, OR you have `OR(AU<=4.9>=3)` which isn't standard. You might have to do `OR(AU<=4.9, AU>=3)` or something to that effect. Check the documentation to see.

Comment: Jeff,
Thank you. I knew I was missing something! Now I get an answer; however there is a problem with how I stated the values for moderate. Low is not registering. Anything under 4.9 is showing as moderate. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(AU<3,"Low",IF(AU<5,"Moderate","High"))
```

Comment: Mike, Thank you very much. That worked. {Of course once I made the change that Jeff said to make as well.

Working equation:
=IF(AU46<3,"Low",IF(AU46<5,"Moderate","High"))

Comment: No problem.  Well spotted Jeff, I had just assumed that `AU` was a named range.

Comment: Thanks. It's been a while since I've done anything in Excel, so I totally forgot about the ability to name ranges. Go figure.